# disable the textfield and setting the value of a hidden field

Tags: jquery

I have a function where i would want to set the value of the hidden textfield and then disable the rest. For example, if i click say 1 on the first set of numbers (1-4), i would want the rest of the number 1s to be disabled. And also each set has its own hidden field so when i click on any number on that set, it will get the number and store it. Here is my code but i can't get it to work. I would appreciate any help. I would appreciate any suggestion on how to get this effect too. Thank you. In this fiddle, i updated the function, i just don't know how to achieve the effect of enable/disable the inputs. http://jsfiddle.net/ph67U/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
for (x=1; x <= 4; x++){
$('.inputRadius' + x).mouseover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('shadow');
});

$('.inputRadius' + x).mouseout(function() {
  if (!$(this).data("sticky")){
    $(this).removeClass('shadow');
  }
});

$('.inputRadius' + x).click(function() {
  $('.inputRadius' + x).data("sticky", false);
  $('.inputRadius' + x).removeClass('shadow');
  $(this).data("sticky", true);
  $(this).addClass('shadow');

      $("#input" + x + x ).attr("disabled",false);
      $("#input" + x + $(this).val()).attr("disabled",true);

  $('#hidvalue' + x).val($(this).val())
});

}

});
```

And here is the html part

```
    <form action="" method="post" name="form1"><strong>Poll?</strong>
    <div style="font-size: 11px;"> Rank From 1 (most excited) to 4.</div>
    <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><label>Option 1</label>
    <div class="numberContainer"><input class="inputRadius1" id="input11" type="text" readonly value="1" /><input id="input12" class="inputRadius1" type="text" readonly value="2" /><input id="input13" class="inputRadius1" type="text" readonly value="3" /><input id="input14" class="inputRadius1 lastInput" type="text" readonly value="4" /><input id="hidvalue1" type="text" name="hidvalue1" value="1" /></div></li>
    <li><label>Option 2</label>
    <div class="numberContainer"><input class="inputRadius2" id="input21" type="text" readonly value="1" /><input id="input22" class="inputRadius2" type="text" readonly value="2" /><input id="input23" class="inputRadius2" type="text" readonly value="3" /><input id="input24" class="inputRadius2 lastInput" type="text" readonly value="4" /><input id="hidvalue2" type="text" name="hidvalue2" value="1" /></div></li>
    <li><label>Option 3</label>
    <div class="numberContainer"><input class="inputRadius3" type="text" id="input31" readonly value="1" /><input id="input32" class="inputRadius3" type="text" readonly value="2" /><input id="input33" class="inputRadius3" type="text" readonly value="3" /><input id="input34" class="inputRadius3 lastInput" type="text" readonly value="4" /><input id="hidvalue3" type="text" name="hidvalue3" value="1" /></div></li>
    <li><label>Option 4</label>
    <div class="numberContainer"><input class="inputRadius4" id="input41" type="text" readonly value="1" /><input id="input42" class="inputRadius4" type="text" readonly value="2" /><input id="input43" class="inputRadius4" type="text" readonly value="3" /><input id="input44" class="inputRadius4 lastInput" type="text" readonly value="4" /><input id="hidvalue4" type="text" name="hidvalue4" value="1" /></div></li></ul>
    <div class="clearfix paddingTop30"></div>
    <p><input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" class="button" /</p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you just have to play with jquery to enable or disable / show or hide your content. When the user click, you just hide.
You can try something like this

```
$(li).click(function(){
     localStorage.setItem('myItem',$(this).value)
     $(this).toggle();
});
```

Hope this help ;)

Comment: Thank you. but i can't toggle just the li since i am dealing with the contents that are inside which are the inputs.